# Add zoom functionality to jquery polaroid gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, photo

I'm using a jquery and css3 photo gallery from  [this](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/creating_a_polaroid_photo_viewer_with_css3_and_jquery.html) site, and I would like to able to enlarge the images onclick.  The author has said there is a way to do this, but not explicitly how (I'm no jquery expert).

I tried creating a separate script that changed the width and height of the image, but I think the existing jquery or css may have been overriding it.
This was just a test to see if I could change it back and forth:

```
var size = false;
function enlarge(){

    if (size == false){
    document.getElementById("photo1").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("photo1").style.height = "100%";
    size = true; 
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('photo1').width = '134px';
        document.getElementById('photo1').height = '134px';
        size = false;
    }
```

Any thoughts as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: Your `var size` needs to be global or something; the `else` block will never execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of three different ways to do what you're asking (just off of the top of my head).

1. Start out with a smaller version of the image and when the user clicks on it, it switches to the larger version (this will have the least amount of blurriness)
2. Change the size of the containing element. Make sure the containing element has the style `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;`
3. Use [CSS3 transformations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) (2D/3D scale)

I've created a jsFiddle demonstrating the last two options (I assume you can easily figure out the first one).

As for the question of whether the plugin is hijacking your style changes, that would take some debugging of your specific code.

[Examples](http://jsfiddle.net/UgKeq/5/)

Comment: I've had success using the css3 scale function you wrote and would like to know how I could apply that function to multiple elements without duplicating the code, myImage1, myImage2 etc...

Comment: @redleaf - It's as simple as adding the css class to the elements that you want to affect.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you pass the function `$(this)` from click function and pass it (enlarge(item)), you should be able to have it happen. you could also have in your else an

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).width = '134px';
    $(this).height = '134px';
});
```

so that you don't have to worry about calling it after you click another one. I'd test it, but not sure what you already have, and putting the whole thing in jsfiddle doesn't work for me (plus not at home, so only using v13, so I couldn't properly test).